# How to set HttpOnly and Secure flags on GA cookies which managed by Google Tag Manager?

Tags: cookies, httponly

My Project use Google Tag Manager(GTM) to manager my google analytic(GA) code. Now, for some reasons, I need to add 'httponly' and 'secure' flags on cookies which GA generated, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Hey brother have you got any solution over this?
if you found then please provide over here, it might help some one some where.

Comment: Hey Ming Sun, did you find any way to achieve this?

Comment: I guess that it is not possible to implement that because GA may track user with both secure and insecure schemas. That's my assumption, and I will update this question if there is a further solution.

Comment: Hello, I believe it is not possible. HttpOnly means the cookie cannot be used by your javascript, but GA cookies are used by your GA libraries, so it would break your GA.